# Database table does not update when prompted to

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is another question I've been meaning to ask for a while about the same "Settlers of Catan" database I asked about in my previous question. This time around it's about updating the database table itself.

I successfully managed to connect the Java application to the Oracle database, and while the other database tables successfully update when prompted to by the application, this one in particular does not for some reason. It gives no errors either, so I exclude it might be a connection or SQL command issue.

Here is the table I want to update:

```
CREATE TABLE giocatore(
    numero INT,
    colore VARCHAR2(20),
    punto_partenza INT,
    punti_vittoria INT DEFAULT 0,
    vittorioso CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f',
    quant_clay INT,
    quant_wool INT,
    quant_wheat INT,
    quant_wood INT,
    quant_rock INT,
    CONSTRAINT player_pk PRIMARY KEY(numero)
    );
```

And here is the Java application code in question:

```
private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        try{
            String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl";
            OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
            ods.setURL(url);
            ods.setUser("LAB_NICK");
            ods.setPassword("10Niroxxe98");
            Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
            String PlayerNumberAsString = playerNum.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int PlayerNumber = Integer.parseInt(PlayerNumberAsString);
            String StartingHexagonNumberAsString = startHex.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int StartingHexagonNumber = Integer.parseInt(StartingHexagonNumberAsString);
            int VictoryPoints = (int) victoryPts.getValue();
            int OwnedAmountOfClay = (int) clayNum.getValue();
            int OwnedAmountOfWood = (int) woodNum.getValue();
            int OwnedAmountOfMinerals = (int) rockNum.getValue();
            int OwnedAmountOfWheat = (int) wheatNum.getValue();
            int OwnedAmountOfWool = (int) woolNum.getValue();
            String PlayerColor = colorChoice.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String IsVictorious;
            if(victoryCheck.isSelected()){
                IsVictorious = "v";
            }else{
                IsVictorious = "f";
            }
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE giocatore SET punti_vittoria = ?, colore = ?, vittorioso = ?, punto_partenza = ?, quant_clay = ?, quant_wool = ?, quant_wheat = ?, quant_wood = ?, quant_rock = ? WHERE numero = ?");
            stmt.setInt(1, VictoryPoints);
            stmt.setString(2, PlayerColor);
            stmt.setString(3, IsVictorious);
            stmt.setInt(4, StartingHexagonNumber);
            stmt.setInt(5, OwnedAmountOfClay);
            stmt.setInt(6, OwnedAmountOfWool);
            stmt.setInt(7, OwnedAmountOfWheat);
            stmt.setInt(8, OwnedAmountOfWood);
            stmt.setInt(9, OwnedAmountOfMinerals);
            stmt.setInt(10, PlayerNumber);
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

I would also like to know how to refresh a JTable, but that's a question for another time. Thank you for your understanding.

EDIT: The code I posted earlier was fully working. Here is the code I was actually asking about. I am deeply sorry for this major inconvenience.

Comment: There's no commit happening in that code, so if your database is not in autocommit mode your transaction will have been automatically rolled-back when it was completed. Can you confirm whether or not your DB is in autocommit mode?

Comment: @JonK Autocommit mode is activated.

Comment: Ah, the updated code snippet shows the actual problem nicely - you've set up your prepared statement and then... closed it without executing it!

Comment: Got it now, what a stupid mistake from me. Thanks!

Comment: Happens to the best of us, you're welcome